# Android Java create bitmap from hex value

Tags: java, android, bitmap

Can anyone suggest a way to create a small solid colored bitmap image from a hex value?

Comment: what have you tried so far? or at least what do you want to achieve, a bit of context would be appreciate

Comment: Haven't tried anything so far. I've just been looking for a way to do it but no luck.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think I may have the answer. Technically I believe it is much easier on Android than on a "pc". The last time I searched to create a bitmap (.bmp), I only found some Android functions and the `BitmapFactory` for non-android, which didn't work for me.

Please look at this site: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html
This point could fit for you:

> `static Bitmap createBitmap(int[] colors, int offset, int stride, int width, int height, Bitmap.Config config)`
>
> Returns a immutable bitmap
> with the specified width and height, with each pixel value set to the
> corresponding value in the colors array.

Answer (score 84):

Alternatively, you can use [Bitmap.eraseColor()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#eraseColor(int)) to set a solid color for your bitmap.

Example:

```
  import android.graphics.Bitmap;
  ...
  Bitmap image = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
  image.eraseColor(android.graphics.Color.GREEN);
```

Answer (score 5):

```
Bitmap image = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
Canvas canvas=new Canvas (image);
int HEX=0xFF888888;
canvas.drawColor (HEX);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `createBitmap()`.

Here is a link that will show you how: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html